# Significant difference between two correlation matrices

Tags: r, logistic, pca, python

We have two huge correlation matrices at different experimental conditions. If we want to identify the significant differences between these matrices , what would be the ideal method. I have implemented PCA for dimentionality reduction for the two matrices, and compared both row by row. Will it give some information regarding the differences. More over how about LDA and logistic regression. Will it give any information.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you really need to find the significance of differences, you first need to precisely define what differences you are interested in. Then you may have to bootstrap.

Comment: I wanted to know whether a particular row differs from same row of another correlation matrix, does they differ significantly or they are similar

Comment: Analysis of correlation matrices may be misleading if the variances are different in different variables in different groups. Equality of "small" ($p << n$) covariance matrices can be tested using likelihood ratio tests (see e.g. [Rencher's book](http://www.amazon.com/Methods-Multivariate-Analysis-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470178965/)) or [the bootstrap](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/3015345). With "huge" matrices (define "huge" please), you may not have enough eigenvalues to get a proper argument in place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a test/technique/method for comparing principal components decompositions between samples?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112900/is-there-a-test-technique-method-for-comparing-principal-components-decompositio)